# New C++ Programmer. Having trouble with loops. How should I fix this program?

Tags: c++

For practice, I'm writing a program that takes in data from the user about the classes they took and at the end, outputs that data into a file of a neat looking transcript with a bunch of calculations such as GPA, total units, etc.

I'm using a `do-while loop` but it doesn't seem to be working.

I believe the problem is with the `addClass` variable, as even though I specified it to only ask for another class if `addClass = 1`, it still asks for one when I input 0. Does anyone who has more experience have a solution to this? Thank you.

```
//Prog: Unofficial Transcript Creator
//Modified 5-08-2018

#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //Declares.
    string classSubject;
    int classCode;
    string professorFirst, professorLast;
    int classUnits;
    string grade;
    int addClass;
    ofstream fout;

    //Open the output file.
    fout.open("UNOFFICIAL_TRANSCRIPT.TXT");

    //Test if the file opened.
    if (fout) {
        cout << "The output file has been located. Please begin input of transcript data." << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "ERROR ID107: The output file was not found. Please create a blank text document named UNOFFICIAL_TRANSCRIPT.TXT.";

    //Prompt user for information.
    do {
        addClass = 0;
        cout << "Please enter the class subject: ";
        cin >> classSubject;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the class code: ";
        cin >> classCode;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the first name of the professor: ";
        cin >> professorFirst;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the last name of the professor: ";
        cin >> professorLast;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "How many units is the class worth? ";
        cin >> classUnits;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "What grade did you get in the class? ";
        cin >> grade;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to add another class? Type 1 for yes or 0 for no. ";
        cin >> addClass;
        cout << endl;

        fout << setw(12) << classSubject << classCode;
    } 
    while
        (addClass = 1);

system("pause");
return 0;
    }
```

Comment: you are reassigning `addClass` use `==`

Comment: `while (addClass = 1);` -- Reread the section of your C++ book that describes how to compare values for equality.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 2):

Replace `while(addClass = 1 )` with `while(addClass == 1)`.

The former will assign the value 1 to addClass and then check whether the value of the expression (which is the value assigned, i.e. 1) is non-zero.
Since this value is non-zero, your loop would never be able to get out of your loop.

The latter performs an equality check to see if the value of `addClass` is equal to 1.

IMHO, `while (addClass = 1)` should also raise a warning on any decent compiler( especially if all warnings are enabled ), as it is a very common mistake/typo.

Also, if it was not a typo, then now would be a good time to brush up your C++ basics.